# Proof of extinction probability in Galton-Watson-process using a Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, martingales, conditional-expectation

this problem is somewhat similar to the thread [The extinction probability of Galton-Watson process from a martingale perspective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447552/the-extinction-probability-of-galton-watson-process-from-a-martingale-perspectiv) I want to show, that for a Galton-Watson-process $Z_0,Z_1,\ldots$ with $Z_0=1$, $\phi(t) = \mathbb E (t^{Z_1})$ the generating function and $\xi \in (0, 1)$ a fixed point of $\phi$:

$\mathbb{P}[\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Z_n = 0\}] = \xi$ using the martingale $\xi^{Z_n}$ and a theorem of Martingale convergence.

Even with the clues from the above thread I wasn't able to solve the problem. Help appreciated!

Comment: maybe there is something really obvious I fail to see???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At time $0$, $\xi^{Z_0}=\xi$. When $n\to\infty$, $Z_n\to+\infty$ on non-extinction hence $\xi^{Z_n}\to0$ on non-extinction and $Z_n\to0$ on extinction hence $\xi^{Z_n}\to1$ on extinction. Finally $|\xi^{Z_n}|\leqslant1$ uniformly, thus everything is in place for an application of martingale dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Did. Actually the question is an exercise for a probability theory course that I am self-studying. Now the only martingale convergence theorem which figures there is the (or just one?) almost sure convergence theorem. So I assume, that the question was supposed to be answered with the help of this theorem. If you don't mind, could you give your opinion on whether there is a solution to the problem with the help of only this convergence theorem?

Comment: Then use your martingale almost sure convergence theorem and the domination condition in my post to apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.